# Move text below picture if picture is aligned to the side

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a image and text. The image is aligned to the left because I want to the text to be next to the image. Both, image and text, are in a `<p></p>`.

Now. I want to insert additional text which would show under previous text and the picture.

How to do this?

Some code:

```
<p><img src="image.gif" align="left" width="300" height="200"> Good paragraph of text</p>
<p>Text that I want to appear below the text and the image above</p>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? What do you mean by "aligned to the left". Are you floating? This question is pretty vague...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add a CSS style attribute to the second `p` like:

```
<p style="clear: both;">
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ac3M/)
- [CSS clear<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clear)